# Excluding inline images in views

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I have a node type with an image field and insert button to get the image into the text field.

Then there is a view that is getting the content of the text field and shortening it to 150 characters. But if there is an inline image at the beginning of the text the view is only showing three points that are linked to the image.

How can I exclude the inline images from views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Rewrite results` option on that field and choose **Strip HTML tags**.

This will "remove" the image from display.

If you have some other HTML inside the Body that you want to keep you can enter them into the `Preserve certain tags` field, for example `<em> <span> <p>`.

Comment: Ok, this was almost too easy :D, thank you!

Comment: One aspect to consider, though, is if media managed images placed inline in the text field are used. Even if HTML is stripped, there can be some text from the image such as `picture`, that's output in the plain text. For that reason, outputting HTML and using `display: none;` in SCSS/CSS to target media elements may be desirable.